# How to dim the background behind my pop up menu after clicking a button?

Tags: java, android

How do I get the background behind my pop up menu to dim after I click the button that opens the popup menu? Looked at other code samples but no luck! Would really appreciate any advice!

```
final Button Bel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnBel);
    final ImageView Phone = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgPhone);
    relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relative);

    Bel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Bel.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            Phone.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            ViewGroup container = (ViewGroup) layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_menu, null);

            popupWindow = new PopupWindow(container, 1000, 850, true);
            popupWindow.showAtLocation(relativeLayout, Gravity.NO_GRAVITY, 221, 4000);

            btnBelNuCall = (Button) container.findViewById(R.id.btnBelNu);
            btnClosePopUp = (Button) container.findViewById(R.id.btnAnnuleren);

            btnBelNuCall.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                    callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:0900-33-44-55-6"));
                    startActivity(callIntent);
                    checkPermission();
                }
            });

            btnClosePopUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    popupWindow.dismiss();
                    Bel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    Phone.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            });

        }
    });
```

Comment: Is there a reason you dont use Dialog? in order to dim the window, you need to have access to a WindowObject, which a PopupWindow does not have access to. Another thing you could do is you could set the dim on the window of your Activity when the action has occured, appearing as if the background is dimmed. Also i'm sure you mean the window behind your PopupWindow right? because dimming the background of your popup is refering to the background **OF** the popup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1. Create A Layout That Covers Everything In Your Main Layout**

I don't know what your XML File looks like, but put something like this at the top of it:

```
<LinearLayout android:id="dim_layout"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:background="#70000000"
   android:visibility="invisible"/>
```

**Note:** Depending on your XML file, you may need to alter this for it to be placed on top of all other components.

This will create a layout covering everything in your main layout with a background of color `#70000000` which is black with an alpha level of 70. Changing the 70 at the beginning of the hex code will allow you to modify how transparent you want it to be.

**2. Show Layout When Popup Is Activated**

```
LinearLayout dim_layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.dim_layout);
popupWindow = new PopupWindow(container, 1000, 850, true);
dim_layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
popupWindow.showAtLocation(relativeLayout, Gravity.NO_GRAVITY, 221, 4000);
```

**3. Hide Layout When Popup Is Deactivated**

```
btnClosePopUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        popupWindow.dismiss();
        Bel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Phone.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        dim_layout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);                
    }
});
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Give an Id to your root tag and in your class, give it the dim background color. For example in your layout activity

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
      <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      android:background="#F4F4F4"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:id="@+id/main_screen">
```

in your class

```
      mainView = findViewById(R.id.main_screen);
      mainView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#30000000"));
```